# SCORM (v 1.2) integration for Quiz module

Tags: quiz

We are looking for SCORM integration with Drupal's [Quiz](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz) module.

Essentially we should be able to Import/Export quizzes and questions as SCORM package(s). Ideal if SCORM player can be used for quiz taking and Results/Feedback displaying.

I couldn't find any library or API to ease up the integration work. Wondering if I have to write my own Importer and Exporter to handle this requirements.

Comment: "Wondering if I have to write my own Importer and Exporter" - probably. Unless it's something Quiz module is supposed to do but does not, in that case you should post an issue in it's issue queue. But I highly doubt it.

Comment: It looks like writing an Importer is not easy, as SCORM is an interface standard not data standard, SCORM package may have questions in any format. So we are planning to go with SCO Node module. However we are interested in getting Quiz module to export SCORM package that can be used by SCO Node module in another site.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Opigno LMS](https://www.drupal.org/project/opigno_lms) distribution, which is fully compliant with SCORM 2004 v3. Here is a quote from its project page:

> Opigno LMS is a full-fledged Learning Management System based on Drupal.
>
> It allows to:
>
> - Manage training paths organized in courses and lessons.
> - Assess students thanks to varied quizzes.
> - Award certificates to successful students.
> - Sell your trainings online.
> - Facilitate interactions thanks to live meetings, forums and chats.
> - ...

Maybe not to start "using" this distribution, but by reviewing it to get an idea about it's SCORM compliance, and then copy-an-paste whatever fits / makes sense to also include in your own site.

Contributed module [SCO Node](https://www.drupal.org/project/sco_node) somehow relates to SCORM and might potentially be of some help to get you going (quote is from its project page):

> The SCO Node module allows nodes to be created that contain SCORM content. The SCO content can then be played and scored on a Drupal 7 site.
>
> The module currently supports SCORM 1.2 and some of SCORM 2004

Comment: The OP is looking for integrating SCORM with the Quiz module. Does that distribution help with that? If it does, in which way does it help?